# Mod_rewrite: Force SSL on specific pages. Add www on none-secure pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this is a common topic, but I've done my utmost to resolve it with the help of the solutions I've found searching the web.

We have a certificate linked to the subdomain secure.mysite.com, and we want to achieve the following:

1. We need to force SSL on the following paths and their subpages:
   http://mysite.com/services[/.../...] => https://secure.mysite.com/services[/.../...]
   http://mysite.com/login[/.../...] => https://secure.mysite.com/login[/.../...]
   http://mysite.com/member[/.../...] => https://secure.mysite.com/member[/.../...]
   http://mysite.com/admin[/.../...] => https://secure.mysite.com/admin
2. We want to add www on all none-secure paths (all paths except the ones mentioned above)
3. We want to remove www on all secure paths (all the ones mentioned above)

The following is what I have put in my .htaccess-file, without success:

```
# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(services|login|member|admin)$ https://secure.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^(services|login|member|admin)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove www from host when HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# add www from host when HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Zend redirect logic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

With some corrections:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(services|login|member|admin) https://secure.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^(services|login|member|admin) http://mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove www from host when HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# add www from host when HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|secure)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the result turns out like this: https://secure.www.mysite.com/login.

Comment: But `https://secure.www.mysite.com/login` is the correct one right? Since it is using HTTPS

Comment: Damn that cache! It turns out the changes doesn't do anything with the SSL, it only forces www: http://www.mysite.com/login

Comment: No, www is not supposed to be included if it's secure (https).

Comment: I don't know what's going on... If it's the cache or something else, but when I removed the browser cache it rewrites to the following (the www should be removed): https://secure.www.mysite.com/login

Comment: I am on mobile now. Will get back to you once I reach back my computer.

Comment: Nice! I believe we are getting somewhere :D. BUT, I forgot to write the last part of the Rewrite which has to do with Zend. Sorry! I'm now being redirected to http://www.mysite.com/index.php. Please, if you still have the time, take a look at my edit (# Zend redirect logic). Your help is much appreciated!