# HTTPS Re-direct issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I'm currently trying to re-direct my users to a https version of the site but only during the booking process and wp-admin sections.

This is the code i'm using courtesy of the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292759/mod-rewrite-force-ssl-on-specific-pages-add-www-on-none-secure-pages)

```
RewriteEngine On
# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(book-on-line|wp-admin) https://test.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^(book-on-line|wp-admin) http://test.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The re-direct works fine if I use the first statement ONLY but doesn't work and just redirects to the homepage if i use the second statement.

The reason for the second statement is that when I go to a secure page, then click a link to move back to a non-secure page, the website still retains the HTTPS when it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure both HTTP and HTTPS is pointing to the same server and document root?

Comment: Well the website is setup on a subdomain and the .htaccess is at the root of where the subdomain is setup.

Does it need to be at the root root as in not "test.mysite" but "mysite"